# Initialize Arraylist in method

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, initialization

Following Question. I have a big amount of `ArrayList attributes` (basically the same as `Kreuzlagerort20kg` etc). Instead of initializing them all in the constructor (the part commented out) i'd love to initialize them inside the `fillLager()` method, making it possible to call the method inside the constructor and have them initialized and filled then. If i do it in the code, i always get a nullpointerexception.

Is it possible and/or sensible to initialize an arraylist inside a method, without getting said nullpointer?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lager {
private ArrayList<Screws> KreuzLagerort20kg,KreuzLagerort50kg;

public Lager(){
        //KreuzLagerort20kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();
        //KreuzLagerort50kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();

        fillLager(1,KreuzLagerort20kg,20);
        fillLager(1,KreuzLagerort50kg,50);
}

public void fillLager(int typ,ArrayList<Screws> lager,double lagerGewicht){

     lager = new ArrayList<Screws>();

     // code that loops through combinations and adds them to the arraylist
    }}}}}}
```

Comment: To be honest there is nothing wrong with the 2 lines you commented out.

Comment: @vikingsteve i would even consider it as a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:
Instead of normally initializing it (like `KreuzLagerort20kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();`) in constructor, you do it in fillLager.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lager {
private ArrayList<Screws> KreuzLagerort20kg,KreuzLagerort50kg;

public Lager(){
        //KreuzLagerort20kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();
        //KreuzLagerort50kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();

        fillLager(1, 20);
        fillLager(1, 50);
}

public void fillLager(int typ, int code){
     if (code==20){
         KreuzLagerort20kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();
     }
     if (code==50){
         KreuzLagerort50kg = new ArrayList<Screws>();
     }


     // code that loops through combinations and adds them to the arraylist
    }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `new` on a variable passed into a method and still have the calling method refer to the original variable, as Java passes by reference.  When you call new X() then there is a new reference and the method which called your other method will not know the variable is now pointing at another reference...

e.g.

```
public void methodA() {
    String s = new String("AAAAA");
    methodB(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public void methodB(String referredString) {
    referredString = new String("BBBBB");
}
```

calling `methodA` will print "AAAAA"

You will need to initialise in the constructor, or make the method return the variables you passed in...

```
public void methodA() {
    String s = new String("AAAAA");
    s = methodB(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public String methodB(String referredString) {
    referredString = new String("BBBBB");
    return referredString ;
}
```

calling `methodA` will now print "BBBBB"

Alternatively - make the string declared outside of either method and don't pass it around at all... e.g.

```
String s = new String("AAAAA");
public void methodA() {
    methodB();
    System.out.println(s);
}

public void methodB() {
    s = new String("BBBBB");
}
```

will also yield "BBBBB"